# Scripting help to allow user interaction to kill process based on output of ps

Tags: bash

I'm taking a stab at this but not doing so well and I'm stuck. I have a user that has limited sudo to run only certain commands. They run multiple commands at times and need the ability to kill certain commands/processes. The command is tcpdump and when its spawned as sudo it creates 2 processes. Ran again and the total is 4. Each 2 is tied to each tcpdump instance, so I have my script finding the PPID and I am going to kill that to take care of child processes. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash 

RESULT1=$(ps -ef | grep "sudo tcpdump" | grep -v grep)
RESULT2=$(ps -ef | grep "sudo tcpdump" | grep -v grep | awk '{print   $3}')
echo $RESULT1
echo $RESULT2
if [ "$RESULT2" = "$RESULT2" ]
then
echo "Choose which PPID you wish to kill"
fi
```

The output looks like this so far:

```
root 14485 14456 0 16:01 pts/0 00:00:00 sudo tcpdump -n -i any port   53 
root 14743 14720 0 16:09 pts/2 00:00:00 sudo tcpdump -n -i any port    220
14456 14720
Choose which PPID you wish to kill
```

My thinking behind

```
if [ "$RESULT2" = "$RESULT2" ]
```

was telling the script somehow that they were ONLY allowed to kill the PPID's it found. (Because they can't have free reign to kill anything) But I'm thinking now that's not the way to achieve this.

I'm drawing blanks on how to tell the script to breakout $RESULT2 so I can provide the options to the user. So, can anyone help me move forward with this so the user can now choose between the PPID's found and have the script only allow them to kill those?

Comment: Use `pgrep -f 'sudo tcpdump'` instead of the `ps` pipelines.

Comment: Also if you want to let them only kill certain pids then don't let them enter a pid. Let them enter a choice number which maps to a pid. Look into `select` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 

RESULT1=$(ps -ef | grep "sudo tcpdump" | grep -v grep)
RESULT2=$(ps -ef | grep "sudo tcpdump" | grep -v grep | awk '{print   $3}')
echo $RESULT1
echo $RESULT2

#Validate existence of PPID before asking for input

if test -z "$RESULT2"; then         ## If no PPIDs
  echo 'No PPID value found' && exit 1    
else
  echo "Choose which PPID to kill" 
  read input
fi

# Get result of whether input matches a value in RESULT2
res=`echo $RESULT2 | grep $input`  

# If input is empty, then

if test -z "$input"; then         
  echo "input empty" && exit 1
elif test -z "$res"; then         # If input doesn't match PPID listed
  echo "input doesn't match PPID" && exit 1
else 
  pkill -P $INPUT             #kill PPID
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: This is great however pkill is not killing the PPID. I will update my post to include the results.

Comment: Disregard - I had capitilized INPUT when I changed the pkill command. Changed it back to lowercase and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

This will always evaluate to true:

```
[ "$RESULT2" = "$RESULT2" ]
```

So it's not a useful test. Instead, you could validate the user input to make sure it equals a line in RESULT2:

```
read input
sudo kill `echo "$RESULT2" |
    awk -v input="$input" 'input==$1'` ||
    echo "Invalid PID"
```